# Performance issue while comparing Pandas Data Frames cell by cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pyspark

I have 2 data frames to be compared cell by cell. Below is the python code that I have written but it is having performance issue.
It took ~2 mins to process 400K rows(90 columns) in each data frames.
Consider 2 data frames df1 and df2 as example:

```
df_diff = (df1 != df2).stack(dropna=None)

df1 = df1.stack()[df_dff]
df2 = df2.stack()[df_dff] 

final = pd.concat( [df1,df2], axis=1 )
final.reset_index(inplace=True)
final.columns = ['row_id', 'Attribute', 'Actual', 'Expected']
```

I need to run this code in my personnel laptop, so I don’t think using dask or spark Data frames  over pandas has any additional benefits to improve performance but I am happy to hear your suggestions if using any of these tools over pandas can improve performance while running on personnel laptop

Thanks

Comment: kindly share a sample of your dataset. We can test your code, see where the bottleneck is or proffer better solutions, if any. 5 to 10 rows is fine

Comment: @sammywemmy: Sorry, unfortunately I can't share data because of sensitive of the data. I tried this code on different datasets  but found similar issue. Let me get some random for you, or you can try this code on any of the sample data if you have. Is there any other approach I can use to compare data frame cell by cell

Comment: not a problem. just create random data and i'll give it a go

Comment: here is the link to sample file saved on Google Drive:    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1boNH75JIf3cKGmwkqHDSyQrnrft-j6KG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: **DO NOT** post images or links for code,data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.  Images can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Also, refrain from posting links to problem definitions and/or explanations Instead, incorporate the explanation into your question directly.